# passive Vs active or omission of 'which is'

Tags: pronouns, passive-voice, whiz-deletion

What is the part of speech of 'regarded' in the following?

> "a quality of beauty and intensity of emotion **regarded** as characteristic of poems" [(NOAD)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/poetry)

Why isn't it "... [which is] regarded ..."?

And in another case:

> "a small lizard with wide feet, **found** especially in warm countries"  [(CALD)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/gecko?q=gecko)

And also:

> "**Words used** to describe writing or speech style" [(Macmillan)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/Words-used-to-describe-writing-or-speech-style)

In all these examples, why shouldn't the verbs be in their passive form (e.g. **which is found**, **words that are used**)?

I am a ESL learner and I am very confused by these usages!

Answer (score 15):

All of these participial usages are examples, as you suggested, of a syntactic rule that deletes a subject relative pronoun and an auxiliary *be* from a relative clause.

The rule is called ***[Whiz](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299)*-Deletion**.  The name is a mnemonic.
The *Wh-* part of *Whiz*-Deletion comes from the fact that relative pronouns start with *wh-*.
The *-iz* part of *Whiz*-Deletion comes from the fact that the most common form of *be* is *is*.
The "Deletion" part of *Whiz*-Deletion means that these are the parts that are deleted.

*Whiz*-Deletion is the source of virtually all post-nominal adjectival phrases, like

- *the man in the Moon*  <== *the man **who is/was** in the Moon*
- *a boy eleven years old* <== *a boy **who is/was** eleven years old*
- *a policeman standing on the corner* <== *a policeman **who is/was** standing on the corner*
- *a locket found in his possession* <== *a locket **which was** found in his possession*

> Since the purpose of an auxiliary *be* is to carry the tense, when the *be* gets deleted, so does the tense; these are tenseless, or "non-finite" -- tensed clauses are "finite". That's why I used "*is/was*" in the examples above -- there's no way to tell which it should be, except in the last example.

Answer (score 5):

It is, brace yourself, a past-participial verbal.  It's a verb phase that functions as an adjective.  It's *equivalent to* the phrase that would be made by adding "which is" or "that is", but it's not an abbreviation.

Comment: *but it's not an abbreviation* I'm wondering how you would prove this, can you help?

Comment: An *abbreviation* is “A shortened or contracted form of a word or phrase, used to represent the whole, utilizing omission of letters, and sometimes substitution of letters, or duplication of initial letters to signify plurality, including signs such as +, =, @” (Wiktionary) None of that is happening here.  It is an elision.

Comment: OED:  2.a. The result of shortening something; an abbreviated or **condensed form, esp. of a text; a summary, an abridgement.**
a1464—2003 -- b. spec. A shortened form of a word or phrase.
1576—2004 -- 3. The action or process of shortening or curtailing something. Also: an instance of this. -- I think either abbreviation (in a general sense) or elision would do.

Comment: In _linguistics_, an abbreviation is a shorted form of a word or phrase.  If someone told you to end a sentence with a period, and you wrote, “The chicken crossed the road Cretaceous”, that would mistaken, however much the Cretaceous really was a geological period.