# I threw a coin in a well that [was] or [is] in the forest

Tags: verbs, compound-adjectives

Which statement is correct and why?

I threw a coin in a well that was in the forest.

vs

I threw a coin in a well that is in the forest.

Also, is the "is/was" before "in the forest" called a linking verb?

Lastly, is the phrase "that [was/is] in the forest" an adjectival phrase that is describing forest?

Comment: Either one is OK, unless the well or the forest has been moved since. This is a perfect place to [use _Whiz_-Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299) to produce _I threw a coin in a well in the forest_. Then you don't hafta worry about past or present tense of _be_, which doesn't mean anytning anyway, and you don't hafta worry about _which_ versus _that_, either. Win-win all around; that's why there are such rules as _Whiz_-Deletion.

Comment: hafta? really? O.o

Comment: @i-CONICA: He's using that for effect. If you doubt he understands English grammar, you're in the minority around here.

Comment: @Robusto I know his credentials. I just think it sounds lazy, especially from someone with his credentials. I don't understand the "effect" it imparts.

Comment: I'm sure it was a deliberate choice, not a lazy one. Prof. Lawler is a careful writer, and if he writes something that sounds odd to you, you should allow the possibility that he means it to sound odd. This isn't a chain of YouTube comments, after all. Assume first that people here are at least as smart as you are.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two options is partly a matter of nuance. The first one, using "was", allows the reader to wonder if perhaps the well no longer exists, while the choice using "is" makes it clear that the well is still there (at the time of writing), and there is more chance the reader could throw a coin into the same well.

The phrase "that was in the forest" is an adjectival phrase, but does not describe the forest, but rather the well.