# “His eyes, still on me, were speaking of cruelty.”

Tags: grammaticality, whiz-deletion

Is this sentence considered correct?

> His eyes, still on me, were speaking of cruelty.

I think whiz-deletion is applied to it, but I am not entirely sure. Can someone tell me?

Comment: Yes, his eyes, (which were) .....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passive Vs active or omission of 'which is'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121615/passive-vs-active-or-omission-of-which-is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, obviously. It's the reduced alternative of:

His eyes, *which were* still on me, were speaking of cruelty.

Such an ellipsis, called ["whiz-deletion"](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=24650) is quite common. (Such an ellipsis, *which is* called "whiz-deletion" is quite common)

Comment: What is "whiz-deletion"? please explain of that term.

Comment: @Yoshiyuki Sekiguchi: Read more by clicking on the term (link) in red.

Comment: @Sankarane: I don't understand the purpose of your edit, but, Hey! it's your answer. :)

Comment: @FF: This wasn't what I meant: "... Here again, "which [were/was/is/etc.] has been deleted." To be precise: "were/was". That's why :-) Thanks for adding the link!

Comment: I'm none the wiser. While I was adding the link, I corrected some mangled [TO BE] forms in your original, but I left your explanatory text pointing out that whiz-deletion *also* involves deleting the conjugated [TO BE] form *(were/was/is/etc.)* associated with whatever subject *which* refers back to. You've just replaced that potentially informative text with what's effectively just a repetition of the penultimate sentence. (But it's *still* your answer! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Say that backwards -- it might make more sense that way.

Comment: @Hot Licks: It's getting late (even for me! :) You look at the edit history and see if you can explain it any better!

Comment: @FF: :-) I thought of making my statement itself into another example:     
Such an ellipsis, called "whiz-deletion" is quite common. (Here again, "which is" has been deleted) - In other words, in my statement "Such an ellipsis, (which is) called... common", "is" is the only applicable form of "to be".