# When do attributive adjectives follow nouns and pronouns?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adjective-position

In the examples below, "big" and "better" are adjectives following a noun and a pronoun (respectively) that they qualify:

1. The couple were shopping for a house **big** enough for their 42 children.
2. I don't like Clinton and Trump; I want someone **better** than those two.

Can someone state a general rule saying when this is done?

Comment: Don't think about it as an adjective following a noun; both are reduced relative clauses. _[Whiz_-Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299) has applied to both _a house (that is) big enough..._ and _someone (that is) better than..._  The normal rule says that if a modifier consists of more than one word, it goes after the noun; only if it is just one word may it precede the noun. Thus _a boy eleven years old_ vs _an eleven-year-old boy_; hyphenation is one way of indicating single-word status.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it generally happens when we are facing an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)). We can rewrite your first sentence into:

- The couple were shopping for a house ***that were*** big enough for their 42 children.

As we can see, ***that were*** is ellipsed in this sentence and ***big*** is qualifying ***enough*** instead ***house***.

In your second example, we have a comparative clause (in which ellipses are almost always implicit), but better is an adverb.

Comment: I'd say "was" rather than "were".

Comment: But "enough" is qualifying "big" and "big" is qualifying "house".

Comment: Not at all. **_that were (was) big enough_** acts as an [adjective phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase) to qualify **_house_**.

Comment: Indeed: "big enough" is an adjective phrase qualifying "house", and "enough" is an adverb qualifying "big".  It's _big enough_, as opposed to (for example) _too big_, or _inadequately big_, or _unimaginably big_, etc.

Comment: It's: was big enough, not were big enough.