# "named" vs "that is named"

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis, whiz-deletion

I want to describe my business and want to refer to it in a sentence.

I am trying to say:

> "In 2015 we established a business (that is) named X".

Intuitively, the "that is" part is redundant, and makes the sentence more cumbersome. But I cannot think of a reason why we should be able to drop the verb.

Is the version without the "that is" part grammatically correct? How can it be explained?

Comment: Without _that is_ the phrase _named X_ is simply adjectival. And if it's not correct, someone should have told Johnny Cash when we wrote _A boy named Sue_.

Comment: You mean Shel Silverstein.

Comment: You are not dropping *the* verb. *The* verb is "established". Try to drop that one, and you will get into serious trouble indeed. But what you are dropping here is just *a* verb somewhere. Not quite sure what you're expecting to hear as an answer to "How can it be explained?". How can it be explained that you can drop "In 2015"? How can it be explained that you can drop "a business named"? You can always drop all kinds of things. And you probably should. In 2015 you founded X. The reader is smart enough to figure out that it must be a business and not a piano or a dog.

Answer (score 5):

There **is** a syntactic rule, called [*Whiz*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299), which is available in certain relative clauses.

Specifically, it can apply to clauses with the following properties:

1. the relative pronoun (*which, who, that*) must be the subject of the relative clause
2. the relative clause must contain a form of the auxiliary *be* immediately following the subject

Any relative clause that meets these criteria may, **optionally** (that means the speaker gets to decide, for any reason at all) delete both the relative pronoun and the auxiliary *be* form, as a unit. Because, as you say, they're redundant, which means predictable and carrying no information.

[The funny name](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299) comes from the fact that the relative pronoun is usually a *wh*-word, and  the auxiliary is usually *is*, so *whiz* deletion is just *Wh-is deletion.* The rule relates sentences like the first sentence in this answer with sentences like

- *There **is** a syntactic rule, called* Whiz-*Deletion, available in certain relative clauses.*

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why you are phrasing it in such a way?

The completed action "named" is implied and not something that has to be spelled out once you share the name of the business--unless, of course, the action of naming it is something you need to highlight.

Entitled

Consider revising the sentence and order of ideas.

"In 2015 we established (add name here), a business that..."

"In 2015 we established (add name here)."

Comment: I ended up revising the whole sentence, but I found this question interesting nonetheless.