# A simple comparison between As vs When

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here's a sentence i have come across online "As kids we didn't complain about being poor".This is the sentence. Actually my question is why the writer used "as kids" in the sentence, have the writer used it to mean "when we were kids"?

"As kids we didn't complain about being poor".

"When we were kids, we didn't complain about being poor".

Are both of the sentences expressing the same meaning??

Answer (score 1):

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-when-or-while), under *as, when and while*, has

> from English Grammar Today
>
> As, when and while are conjunctions. In some uses as, when and while
> can mean the same, but they can also have slightly different meanings.
> We use them to introduce subordinate clauses.

though this isn't a full explanation (although I'd argue that subject/verb deletion from an original like 'when we were kids,' ... to 'when kids,' ... licenses the 'conjunction' label here).

On the other hand, [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as) looks at the surface structure here:

> *as* preposition ...
>
> 2 During the time of being (the thing specified)
>
> ‘he had often been ill as a child’

In 'As managing director, I have to make tough decisions', 'as' means 'in my role / capacity as' or 'Because I am'. This usage undoubtedly adds at least a nuance to the meaning of 'as' in 'As kids we didn't complain about being poor', but I'd say that the purely temporal 'When we were kids ...' is a closer paraphrase.

Comment: I would feel much more comfortable with the concept _whiz deletion_ were you yourself not the author of the first Google hit for the term.

Comment: That's positively scary. Look up Prof John Lawler's articles here on ELU. He practically wrote the book. I hope he doesn't sue me. (And I expect others not to be blindly prescriptive here, so I'll mention that CGEL doesn't favour the analysis.)

Comment: No I don't think from "when we were kids" to "when kids" is whiz-deletion, if we go by [John Lawler's definition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/363601/330274). That clause doesn't satisfy the conditions listed in John Lawler's answer. It seems to be a plain case of ellipsis.

Comment: Yes; it's subject (+ verb) deletion.

Comment: You're right, Eddie; it's subject (+ verb; almost always _be_) deletion after _if, when, where, while, though_ .... << When ØØ not at home in Addlethorpe, he often used to eat out. >> Interesting that 'As kids, we used to ...' can't be expanded to 'As we were kids, we used to ...'.