# Indirect complement or postmodifier in a noun phrase

Tags: comparisons, modifiers, complements, syntactic-analysis

In the sentence

[1] He is the most talented artist (that) I know

what is *(that) I know* in terms of function – an indirect complement, licensed by *most*, or simply a common postmodifier? Why?

Similarly, what is *in the world* in

[2] the most talented artist in the world

and why?

**Addition to the original post:**
Having read the answer and the comments that I've received for this question, along with answers to other questions about licensing and the modifier/complement distinction, I have to give this another go:

According to the comments below, we are dealing with modifiers rather than (indirect) complements in both the above examples. Now, I'm not doubting the ***validity*** of these comments – I just still don't ***understand***. This is why:

As far as I've been able to understand, licensing is all about setting up "slots" for specific kinds of structure. For instance, a verb such as *give* sets up a slot for something being given, and a slot for a recipient; consequently it licenses two object complements (direct and indirect object). Part of the deal is also that the slots set up are specific to a subset of "licensers"; in this case: not all verbs license two objects.

Now, to me it seems that this 'setting up slots that are specific to a certain subgroup' is exactly what superlatives do, something that, I think, is supported by John Lawler's answer below:

> *Most is a superlative marker and takes a superlative construction. One of the things required for the construction is a range for comparison*

Looking again at [1] and [2], it seems to me that both the relative clause in [1] and the prepositional phrase (PP) in [2] elaborate on the "range-for-comparison-slot" set up by *most*; hence, they should both be licensed by *most*, no?

Now, if these dependents are indeed licensed, they should be complements – shouldn't they? Only, since they aren't licensed by the head noun, but rather by another constituent within the noun phrase (NP), they'd be indirect complements.

This is my take on all this – could someone please explain to me where I go wrong, and how I should think instead?

Comment: I've edited in quote marks, because the italics on their own were a bit unclear.

Comment: @Hannah "(that) I know" is a relative clause modifying "artist". In your other example, the PP "in the world" is complement of "artist".

Comment: @BillJ Would it be possible for you develop this in an actual answer? I'd be very interested to know more about the way in which the PP is a complement, and also your thoughts on the fact that the relative clause "(that) I know" seems to connect with the head noun in a whole different way in the original example, compared to the way it connects in "the artist that I know", where it's clearly and indisputably a postmodifier. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have much to add. Relative clauses are modifiers, not complements, so the matter of licensing does not arise. On reflection, though, I would say that the PP "in the world" is a modifier not a complement since it doesn't have to be licensed by the head noun "artist".

Comment: @BillJ Ok – then I understand in "in the world", thanks!  :) I had no idea that relative clauses were always automatically modifiers though – good to know :) I just think there is a clear difference in the connection between the head noun and the relative clause depending on whether or not we keep "most talented", but I suppose it's just my intuition that fails me then. Thanks again!

Comment: @BillJ I've edited my OP in accordance with your comments; I'd be truly, truly grateful for a response to this :)

Answer (score 2):

Both of these are simply the Superlative construction.

*Most* is a superlative marker and takes a superlative construction. One of the things required for the construction is a range for comparison, which can be expressed as a relative clause modifying the superlative NP:

- *He is the tallest boy **who is in the class**.*

Of course, such relative clauses are often trimmed down to prepositional phrases by [Whiz Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299):

- *He is the tallest boy **in the class**.*

In your terms, yes, it's a post-modifier and it's licensed by *most* (or by *-est*).
If you called it an indirect complement I'd be puzzled, but that's nothing new.
I don't know what you'd call a reduced relative clause.
It may be a heretical notion, though it's not a new one.

Comment: Thanks @John Lawler! I'm confused by the part about being licensed, but still being a modifier though... and also, if it is indeed licensed by "most", it has to be indirect, right? So your answer seems a little bit contradictory to me. I'm sure it's just me being a bit slow though, so if you could clarify, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "indirect". Licensing has to do with particular constituents that allow other constituents to occur, the way [negation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) licenses negative polarity items like _ever_ or _any_

Comment: Sorry, I'm speaking in CaGEL's terms – I haven't got it with me at the moment, so I can't give page references unfortunately... but like "than this" in "a longer lecture than this" which is an indirect complement in the NP, since it's licensed by "-er" in "longer" rather than by the head noun. As for licensing, I agree, but I thought that was the whole point of the distinction between complements and modifiers – that complements, but not modifiers, need to be licensed, so I don't quite understand how it's not a complement if it needs to be licensed... see what I mean?

Comment: That may be the whole point of the distinction between complements and modifiers, but frankly I don't find that to be a useful distinction, and I don't use it. Nothing particular hinges on it; it's just pilpul.

Comment: Pilpul – haha, I kind of agree, actually... I was just revisiting the idea of licensing and thinking basically just that. Might post a question about it, because as far as I can see quite a lot does hinge on it in CaGIL...

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have figured out the answer to my own question!

[1] He is the most talented artist **(that) I know**

[2] He is the most talented artist **in the world**

I think the reason that the relative clause and the PP here seem like complements is that although they are modifiers, they are modifiers not of the head noun *artist*, but rather of the head of the NP complementing an ellipted PP – where the ***ellipted PP*** in turn functions as a complement licensed by *most*:

[1a] He is the most talented artist **of all the artists that I know**

[2a] He is the most talented artist **of all the artists in the world**

What do you think?