# Is it Gerund or adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech, gerunds, present-participles, whiz-deletion

I don't understand the function of **"coming"** word in the sentence below.

> ... as they weigh the scale of monetary easing **coming** later this
>   month.

Is it working as a gerund? and if so, why is it in gerund?

Could i rewrite:

> As they weigh the scale of monetary easing **which is** coming later his month.

Comment: This may be a matter of false friends that leads to confusion. In English, the things that people call gerunds are *‑ing* verb phrases where the grammar is expecting a noun phrase. This contrasts with the things that people call participles, which are *‑ing* verb phrases but where here the grammar is expecting a modifier not a substantive. In Spanish, *gerundios* are always adverbs never substantives as they are in English, and so for substantive use of verb phrases, Spanish uses the infinitive instead, as English can do but isn't obliged to.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could.

"Coming" is a participle, in the small clause obtained by [Whiz deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/547)