# Using auxiliary with past participle

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles

I was searching on the meaning of skirt in Longman dictionary and I found the definition which is: "a piece of outer clothing worn by women and girls", Why did not he say: "a piece of outer clothing **is worn** by women and girls", Why did they not use an auxiliary verb?

Comment: It is sometimes called a _whiz deletion_, "A phenomenon where the relative pronoun and the verb "to be" are removed from certain relative clauses." In this case _which is_ was removed.

Comment: It is done simply to save space.

Comment: You only use auxiliary verbs in verb phrases. Definitions of nouns are noun phrases. This is not passive voice. _Worn_ is a reduced participle from a relative clause, which would contain a relative pronoun as well as an auxiliary verb. So the answer is that an auxiliary verb would be ungrammatical without a relative pronoun as well. [_Whiz_-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299) removes both of them at the same time, for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a piece of outer clothing worn by women and girls" is not a complete sentence. 
In a sentence it would be:

> A skirt is a piece of outer clothing worn by women and girls

Past participles can be used together with an auxiliary verb to form a sentence or without one and then they act as adjectives.

It's the same as saying:

> a piece of outer clothing **that is** worn by women and girls