# Omitting Relative Pronoun and verb "be"

Tags: relative-pronouns, be, omissibility, whiz-deletion, zero-copula

Could someone please explain, why the pronoun and the verb "be" are omitted in the following sentence?

"it allows communication even for people far away from each other"

Shouldn't this sentence be "it allows communication even for people WHO ARE far away from each other"?

Comment: This is a common rule in English syntax, called [_Whiz_-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299).

Comment: They aren't omitted *per se*. They simply are not needed. *Ars longa, vita brevis.* :)

Comment: Right. You don't have to recycle them or anything.

Comment: There's no deletion of "who are". The expression "far away from each other" does modify "people", though it's not some kind of relative clause but a preposition phrase. Syntactically it's no different to "a tree [by the gate]" or "a hut [in the forest]", where the bracketed PPs modify "tree" and "hut" respectively.