# Dangling modifier or gerund

Tags: gerunds, dangling-participles

Is the 'dangling modifier' concept always associated with Adverbial participles? Is it not applicable to Gerunds?

Consider the following sentence, please:

You waste most of your time doing unnecessary things.

As far as I know, the participle 'doing' is acting like a Gerund here, and therefore, I think, its passivisation is also possible:

Most of your time is wasted doing unnecessary things. 
Am I right?

Active: I spent a lot of time cleaning that room.

Passive: a lot of time was spent cleaning that room. (??)

Active: You can adjust the temperature by turning this button.

Passive: the temperature can be adjusted by turning this button.

Stir the ingredients until well blended.

In the last example, I think a 'being' is missing. For example,

'Stir the ingredients until being well blended.' To make the second part a Gerund phrase. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dangling modifier" is only applied to participial phrases without overt subjects. These are normally adverbial, and they may be present participles. Though not gerunds. Gerunds are noun clauses, headed by *-ing* verbs, and their subjects are either present, or determined by the syntax:

- ***Bill's arriving two hours late** turned out to be bad luck for us.*
- *Bill was cautioned about **arriving more promptly next time**.*

So never mind danglers; they're not involved. Instead, the concept of "passive" seems confused here. E.g,

> As far as I know, the participle *doing* is acting like a Gerund here, and therefore,
>   I think, its passivisation is also possible:
>
> - *Most of your time is wasted doing unnecessary things.* Am I right?

No.
First, the *doing* clause is not a gerund, but an adverbial participle, meaning *while* doing unnecessary things.
Second, even if it were a gerund, that would say nothing about its passivization.
Third, the passive *is wasted* in the example sentence is in the **main** clause, not the *doing* clause.
Fourth, the *doing* clause is active, **not** passive, in all the given example sentences.

In the other examples given, it's the same phenomenon -- the *-ing* clause has nothing to do with the passive, because it's in a subordinate clause, while the passive is in the main clause.

> Active: *I **spent** a lot of time cleaning that room.*
>   Passive: *A lot of time **was spent** cleaning that room.*
>   Active: *You can **adjust** the temperature by turning this button.*
>   Passive: *The temperature can **be adjusted** by turning this button.*

Note that *by turning this button* and *cleaning that room* do not change to passive; only the main verbs.

Finally,

> - *Stir the ingredients until well blended.*
>
> In the last example, I think a *being* is missing. For example,
>
> **Stir the ingredients until being well blended.*
>   To make the second part a Gerund phrase. Am I right?

No again. All the other examples were passivized in the main clause. But the main clause here is an imperative. Imperatives have no passive. So you're trying to passivize what's left, but *well blended* is not even a clause, certainly not a participle or gerund. No verb, right? No verb, no passive. So that's right out.

What's happened is that *until well blended* comes from *until (they are) well blended* by [*Whiz*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299). So your intuition that there should be some form of *be* is right; but not the *-ing* form.

Comment: Thanks. You say ""Dangling modifier" is only applied to participial phrases without overt subjects. These are normally adverbial, and they may be present participles." So, are the  passive example sentences in the OP exceptional, because the adverbial participles in them do not form dangling cases; as in "Most of your time is wasted doing unnecessary things"? Would you also agree that NOT ALL adverb participles are "dangling participles?" Thank you.

Comment: Of course they aren't. Danglers are mistakes, where the structure's been screwed around so that the subject of a participle is not easily parsed, like _Sitting on a fence, my grandmother saw three cats_, where it sounds like my grandmother was sitting on the fence instead of the cats. That's a dangling participle. _Doing unnecessary things_ is not, since its subject is clearly defined and there's no confusion.