# I heard <Mona singing that song> <the song sung by Mona>. [parse]

Tags: clauses, modifiers, objects, participial

> **(1)** *I heard Mona singing that song*.
>
> **(2)** *I heard the song sung by Mona*.

"*Mona singing that song*" and "*the song sung by Mona*" are objects, each of which can be parsed two ways: "head noun phrase + its participial modifier" or "participial clause". Is it right? Thanks!

Comment: Both are grammatical, but in #1 you heard the singer and in #2 you heard the song.

Comment: Lawrence, What conclusion should I make from this? Thanks!

Comment: That word-order in English is significant.

Comment: With format #2, it's at least *possible* you never actually heard ***Mona*** singing the song - the intended meaning could be something along the lines of *I heard **someone else** singing **that song which Mona sings**.*

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to parse the two sentences, and they do have similar meanings, in that they can both be used to describe the same event. But they have completely different structures and their parses are not the same. Partly this is due to [the wide range of syntactic structures available to sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) like *hear*, but also to the fact that English usually has several different ways to say anything.

> (1) *I heard [Mona singing the song].* (let's leave *that* out of this, OK?)

has a very simple Subject-Verb-Object structure. The Direct Object of *heard* is the gerund clause *Mona singing that song*, which is a noun phrase and can be an object. That's a very common construction with transitive non-volitional sense verbs: *I saw him arriving, I felt him striding,* etc.

The gerund clause still has its subject *Mona*, but it's not a participial phrase; it's a complement clause. Gerunds use *-ing* verb forms, which are technically called participles, but they don't form participial phrases, which are modifiers. Gerunds are used as nouns, not modifiers.

> (2) *I heard [the song [sung by Mona]].*

on the other hand, has been transformed by [*Whiz*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299), stripping off the markers from the relative clause in

(3) *I heard the song [**that was** sung by Mona].*

and producing what's often called a truncated relative, which is a variety of participial phrase. They are modifiers, like relative clauses, and not nouns like gerund clauses.

So in (2) the speaker is saying what they heard was the song that was (or is -- tense is not available when auxiliaries are deleted) sung by Mona. It could be that Mona made the song famous, and the speaker heard someone else sing it. This is not the case in (1), where the event of Mona's singing is what the speaker said they heard. So, while they can both describe the same event in some cases, they approach the task from different directions and use different means. And different meanings.

Comment: How is it different in (3) if *it* is substituted for *the song* as in "I heard it sung by Mona"? There seems to be no Whiz-Deletion there, and is the same parse available for (3) in its original form?

Comment: The speaker saying _I heard it sung by Mona_ is reporting the experience of hearing _it_ (whatever that was) being sung by Mona (possibly in recording and not in person), and not by someone else. _Sung by Mona_ can't be a reduced relative here because relative clauses can't modify pronouns, so it has to be a reduced participial clause, which is one meaning of _I heard Mona singing_ (= _I heard Mona as she was singing_).

Comment: John Lawler, "_I heard [Mona [singing the song]]_." = "_I heard Mona who was singing the song_." - why cannot it be a variant of parsing this sentence either? Thanks!

Comment: It can be, though the intonation would be different. It's not ambiguous in speech, only in writing, since the orthography doesn't represent most of the language.

Comment: So can "I heard **the song** sung by Mona" be construed to employ the same reduced participial clause ("sung by Mona") as "I heard **it** sung by Mona"?

Comment: @Robusto If you intend the boldface to indicate stress, the second example is ungrammatical. Pronouns like _it_ don't get contractively stressed. And any written sentence can be parsed and construed in a plethora of ways, [as Abney pointed out](http://www.vinartus.net/spa/95c.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler: No, I didn't intend to indicate stress, only calling those out for easier reading.

Comment: JohnLawler, "_Mona was singing the song_." is a sentence. We add it as an object to "_I heard_" and get "_I heard Mona singing the song_.". Therefore, we can say "_Mona singing the song_" is a clause. But why cannot I apply the same logic to the second sentence? I mean: "_The song was sung by Mona_." is a sentence. We add it as an object to "_I heard_" and get "_I heard the song sung by Mona_.". Therefore, we can say "_the song sung by Mona_" is a clause too.