# If I were to remove the "which is" or "that is" from an adjective clause, which type of adjective phrase is formed?

Tags: adjectives, participles, participial

Example with adjective clause:

- Your pictures are stored in the Gallery **which is accessible from My Dashboard**.

If I were to remove "which", would the result be just an adjective phrase, if so what type?

- Your pictures are stored in the Gallery **accessible from My Dashboard**.

I want to say it's an attributive adjective phrase, but I'm unsure.

..

I also played around with participles.
This is just a bonus question. Would the bold part be called a **past participial phrase**?

- Your pictures are stored in the Gallery **found from My Dashboard**.

Comment: The two sentences are exactly the same, grammatically, aside from the fact that in the second one *which is* (or more commonly *that is*) is missing but *assumed* to exist.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but in essence by taking away the "is" in "which is" you are taking away the linking verb from the predicate adjective phrase, "accessible from My Dashboard"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passive Vs active or omission of 'which is'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121615/passive-vs-active-or-omission-of-which-is):  'What is the part of speech of 'regarded' in the following?

"a quality of beauty and intensity of emotion regarded as characteristic of poems" ' ... JohnLawler: ' ... Whiz-Deletion is the source of virtually all post-nominal adjectival phrases....'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, thank you! I think then this would be a past participial phrase and also an attributive adjective phrase.