# Use of which in a sentence

Tags: commas, appositives, which-that, whiz-deletion, possessive-of-which

In the following sentences, is it necessary to use **which**?

1. SRH, a recombination model, is used for direct bandgap materials.
2. SRH, which is a recombination model, is used for direct bandgap semiconductors.

If both are correct, please explain the use of **which** in those cases.

Comment: Both of the sentence are grammatical; in other words, you don't have to use _which is_ (here is a missing _is_ as well). Together they make up _which is_, a typical target for the syntactic rule [_Whiz_-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299). Like all syntactic rules, this doesn't change the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The two variants are both grammatical.

(1) has 'a recombination model' (correctly offset, as it is a non-defining parenthetical, by commas) as an explicative / descriptive *appositive*.

(2) uses a non-defining *relative clause* (correctly, as it is non-defining, set off by commas) to add the additional information.

Comment: Please let me know the usage situation of those two cases.

Comment: I'd say they're virtually identical in their distribution. Neither would give rise to the slightest raising of an eyebrow.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

In 1, “SRH” and “a recombination model” are in apposition, suggesting an equivalence between them. The equivalence need only be partial. Thus, all that we know about SRH is that it is a member of the set of recombination models; all we know about the set of recombination models is that it contains SRH. The same analysis could be done with “I saw a tree, a green thing” or “I saw a green thing, a tree”. In each example the overlap of equivalence is partial.

In 2, “which is a recombination model” is separated from the main flow of meaning (“SRH is used ...”) by commas. It is therefore a supplementary clause that qualifies SRH. The logical considerations of partial equivalence still apply.

I conclude that both are clear, unambiguous and correct and that there is no difference in meaning.