# Is it correct that this sentence is supposed to have a relative inside?

Tags: grammar

I am reading a book and there's one sentence: "race-mixing becomes a crime worse than treason." (from Born A Crime by Trevor Noah)

I wonder how "crime" and "worse" connect? is it okay to just put the adjective behind or there is " which is" between them?

So the original should be " a crime (which is) worse than treason"?

Thanks!!!

Comment: The sentence is fine as is, it isn't supposed to have extra words. I don't think "original" is the word you want for the concept, but yes, "a crime which is worse than treason" is the meaning.

Comment: _Clause cutting_ is a tool in every writer's toolbox to do away with verbiage. Yes, there is a _which is_ (precisely, _that is_) between the two words.

Comment: Hi, thank you guys. So how about this sentence: "The guy who is my brother is playing the piano." is it okay to remove "who is" and turn it into "The guy my brother is playing the piano."?

Comment: Congratulations; you've rediscovered (parts of) what linguists call "deep structure" and "transformational grammar". That means the "underlying" organization and how it changes; here it's a relative clause, which gets operated on by a syntactic rule called [_Whiz_-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299) that removes the predictable _which is_ part of the relative clause.