# What's the grammatical function of the following phrase in bold?

Tags: grammar

> We saw a blue sky for the first time in weeks, **perhaps a good
> omen.**

I'm not sure if the phrase in bold is called a reduced relative clause in grammar. Actually it modifies the whole sentence that comes before it.

Comment: It looks to me like a noun phrase, in apposition to "blue sky".

Comment: @AndreasBlass, The blue sky alone is not a good omen. Seeing a blue sky for the first time in weeks is a good omen.

Answer (score -1):

It is a reduced relative clause and it is true that this relative modifies the whole previous clause. Although [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses-referring-to-a-whole-sentence) seems to indicate that this use is more often encountered in spoken language, it is often used in written formal language too:

> Some relative clauses refer to a whole clause, a whole sentence, or a longer stretch of language. We always use ***which*** to introduce these clauses. We often use these clauses in informal speaking to express an opinion or evaluation.
>
> - I think the other thing that was really good about it as well was that [*everybody worked really hard and helped tidy up at the end*], **which** I hadn’t expected at all. (In this example, the ***which*** clause modifies the italicised clause).

So your example could be re-written with the omitted words:

> *We saw a blue sky for the first time in weeks*, *[**which*** *was]* perhaps a good omen.

here again, the which clause modifies the italicised clause.

***Edit:*** I am ready to accept I am wrong and learn something new. I just wish people made the effort to also give the right answer, which they must know since they downvoted. When someone gives a correct answer, I will gladly delete mine.

Comment: Even if there were such a thing as a 'reduced relative clause' (which there isn't) it wouldn't be one! In any case, a so-called 'reduced relative clause' is a non-finite clause.

Comment: But famous grammar books have made enough references to reduced relative clauses!

Comment: Even if @BillJ separates himself from the term 'reduced relative clause' with scare quotes, it is widely used and it is meaningful; practically inevitable in a transformational theory. The sentence _We saw a blue sky for the first time in weeks, **which was/is** perhaps a good omen_ (in either tense) is reduced by the transformation called _[Whiz_-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299), which deletes the boldfaced parts, producing the example sentence, with no meaning change. This is not rocket surgery; it's very ordinary grammar.

Comment: @JohnLawler Encouraging comment. I was wondering if BillJ was thinking of it as an aside. Could be. As in, _We saw a blue sky for the first time in weeks, **and this was/is** perhaps a good omen._